# mysql: change all columns of a table from varchar to decimal

Tags: mysql

I have a table with all columns of type varchar, but the data are actually numbers, i.e. decimal(6,2) would be more appropriate. How can I change all columns from varchar to decimal if there are a lot of columns.
Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can change an individual column to decimal by using `ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY COLUMN columnname DECIMAL(6,2);` . Any strings that can be converted to numbers will be converted, and others will be changed to zero.

If you want to be certain of doing this non-destructively, you could instead do `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN` to add a decimal column, and then `UPDATE tablename SET decimalcolumn = textcolumn` , and then use a SELECT to check for any rows where `textcolumn` and `decimalcolumn` aren't equal (it does type conversion as part of the comparison, so `"5"` and `5.00` are equal, as you'd want).

I don't know of a way to automatically apply the same conversion to multiple columns at once, though you could do it in PHP or another programming language by selecting a row from the table, looping over the columns that are returned, and running MODIFY for each one. If there are only a few columns, it's probably easier to do it by hand.

Comment: Thanks for responding. It's unfortunately a lot of columns, so I was hoping there is a way to do that even though I couldn't find anything with a search engine.

Comment: Oh, I know! You could use mysqldump to get a dump of your table, then go to the CREATE TABLE command and change all the `varchar`s to `decimal`s. Then drop the original table and re-create it from the dump. It will still be using quoted strings in the INSERT statement, but that's not a problem because they'll automatically be converted to the appropriate number type.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's `ALTER TABLE` statement supports changing multiple columns at once. In fact, doing as many changes to a table's schema as you can in one statement is preferred and highly recommended. This is because MySQL copies the whole table to do a schema change, but only does the copy once per `ALTER TABLE` statement. This is an important time saver when modifying a very large table!

That said, you can rehearse your changes in a couple of ways.

Firstly, I would use a development database to test all this, not a production one. You can then use `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE ...` to create a structurally identical table and then use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM ...` to copy the data. Now you can experiment with `ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY COLUMN ... DECIMAL(6,2)`. If you do this on one column and get the message `0 Warnings`, then that column will convert without incident and you can test the next. If you do get warnings, then `SHOW WARNINGS` will show a number of them so you know what problem MySQL encountered.

Depending on how well you know the data, you can also do a number of different `SELECT`s to find and filter it to see how much of it might be out of range or unconvertable (e.g. blank or text instead of numbers).

Yes, this approach will take some time, but once you're happy with this, you can assemble all the `MODIFY COLUMN` clauses into the one statement and run it on the real table.

Comment: That's neat and useful to know. Also, I'm not sure whether to be horrified that that's how ALTER TABLE actually works (making a new copy of the entire table!), or amazed that they made it function so smoothly from the user's perspective despite that.

Comment: The table-copy is an artefact of the multiple-storage engine model and has been like that way since the very start. For its disadvantages, it does have some advantages: for example, it makes for a stupidly simple way to rebuild all the indices :-). BTW, the MySQL docs are very exhaustive; it sounds like you should invest some time in there.

Comment: That's a very polite way of putting it (:

Comment: I actually have been going systematically through the MySQL docs. They're surprisingly readable!